# How to extract text from a Specific Area in a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to extract Text from a PDF using Python, and I have successfully done so using PyPDF2 like this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
reader = PdfFileReader('path.pdf')
page = reader.getPage(0)
page.extractText()
```

This extracts all the Text from the Page, but I want to extract the text only from a Rectangular region of 3'x4' at the top-left part of the page.

I Basically want to do something like :[How-to extract text from a pdf doc within a specific rectangular region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297931/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-doc-within-a-specific-rectangular-region) but in Python

Can this be done by PyPDF2 or by any other Python Library?

Comment: Did you get any option to extract? Do you have any solution?

Comment: @NareshR No I didn't

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather complex topic, but it is possible. 
First you need to get familiar with the pdf format descripton.

Start [here](http://www.printmyfolders.com/understanding-pdf) for example.

You can identify the location and contents of the text boxes and extract the string data.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436474/pypdf-for-indirectobject-extraction) topic holds examples for pyPdf, the previous version of PyPDF2, but syntax is similar. There are examples on how to iterate through the indirect objects.

A good place to start is also the source of the function [pageObj.extractText()](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645) that you used.

If you are not restricted to Python: [How to extract text from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650957/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf)

You can also use a tool like [iText RUPS](https://github.com/itext/rups/releases/tag/5.5.9) to inspect the pdf. It shows how the content is rendered and placed on the page:

[image]

Afterwards you should be able to identify and address the elements and extract their content.